# Coherent vs Incoherent 2 photon scattering from 2 level system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, atomic-physics

I'm struggling to calculate the s-matrix elements for 2 photon scattering from a 2 level system. I'm trying to understand the difference between coherent and incoherent scattering and following the paper https://hal.science/jpa-00209720/document. So far I've been trying to use time dependent perturbation theory to try to arrive at equation 3.2 but I'm getting a divergent answer.

The context if the following: we have a 2 level system $|g>$, $|e>$ with excitation energy $\hbar \omega_0 $ in a laser field with $N$ photons in mode $\lambda_L$. We want to calculate the matrix elements from $|\psi_i> = |g, N\lambda_L>$ to $|\psi_f> = |g, (N-1)\lambda_L, \lambda>$.

I'm treating the dipole interaction as a perturbation so the unperturbed Hamiltonian would be $H_0 = \hbar \omega_0 b^\dagger b + \hbar \sum_{\lambda}\omega_\lambda a^{\dagger}_{\lambda} a_{\lambda}$ and the interaction $V = -\mathbf{d} \cdot (b^{\dagger} \mathbf{E^+} + b \mathbf{E^-})$, with $\mathbf{E^+} = \sum_{\lambda} \mathbf{\varepsilon}_{\lambda} a_{\lambda}$ and $\mathbf{E^-}=\sum_{\lambda}\varepsilon^*_{\lambda} a^{\dagger}_{\lambda}$ and $\varepsilon_{\lambda}$ is the polarization of the emitted photon. If I'm not wrong the 1st order term in the $\hbar$ expansion is 0, and the second order term is

$-\frac{1}{\hbar^2} \int_0^\infty dt \int_0^t dt^{'} e^{it(\omega_\lambda - \omega_0) +it^{'}(\omega_0 - \omega_L)} <g, (N-1)\lambda_L, \lambda|V|e, (N-1)\lambda_L><e,(N-1)\lambda_L|V|g,N\lambda_L>$

Then one can also consider intermediate emission and reabsorptions, and I'm trying to show that taking these into accounts one gets the S-matrix element

$\frac{2i\pi}{\hbar^2}\delta(\omega_{\lambda} - \omega_L) \frac{\hbar \Omega}{2}\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\omega_L - \omega_0 + \frac{i\Gamma}{2}}(-\mathbf{d}\cdot\mathbf{\varepsilon}^*_{\lambda})$.

I can see that the first matrix element gives the $\mathbf{d}\cdot \varepsilon^*_{\lambda}\sqrt{N}$ and the second gives the $\frac{\hbar \Omega}{2}$ ($\Omega$ is the Rabi frequency). I can also see that the $\Gamma$ (lifetime) term comes from adding in all possible re-emissions and re-absorptions but it's the integration of the exponential that I'm confused about. Clearly the delta comes from here but don't you have a divergent term too? Do you need some regularization or am I messing up my perturbation theory? I haven't gone so far as to calculate the s-matrix element for the transition to $|g,(N-2)\lambda_L, \lambda, \lambda'>$ but I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint or some reference where S-matrix theory is applied in this context rather than QFT.

Thank you! :)